# Questions about application level locking with Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to get some simple app level locking, my DB schema is fairly simple, just

- id(int)
- name
- expiration(datetime2)
- ownerId(nvarchar(100))

This will be used both in a web app and in a cli app that's multi-threaded.

The goal is to have an underlying interface such that you can do something like so:

```
var l = LockerThing.Create(myLockName, myOwnershipId)

l.getLock();
l.refreshLock();
l.releaseLock();
```

Underneath if no lock record exists for that key, a record is created, otherwise the record is retrieved and then we interact with it at that point.

My concern is how this interacts with the DbContext, specifically with saving database changes.  I want to create and save the updates to the lock object immediately because the locks need to be checked/verified by other applications and so it cannot wait.

However, if the user of this class happens to have changes registered in the DbContext that they're not ready to commit just yet, the save can cause problems.  Or worse yet, it could be in a transaction that doesn't committed for a bit.  All of these problems can be worked around by having the caller be aware of these issues, but I'd prefer not having that be the case.

I'm considering just have the locking stuff be an island unto itself.  It gets its own DbContext so it can work as directly as possible with the DB.  It doesn't really interact with any other part of the system, and no other part of the system should be interacting with the locking tables.

Any opinions on this?  Any suggestions?  For those who have created these sorts of things using Entity Framework in the past, what would your recommendation be?

Comment: EF is not the correct tool to use for this. You don't need the Unit Of Work pattern (it actually works against your purpose) and you don't need the Repository abstraction. I would recommend straight up ADO.NET. It is only a few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually my thought as well and I've been fighting against myself to just start writing raw SQL.  The project itself uses EF and so I've been trying to stay within those bounds as much as possible.